# Logging the output of a management command run by a cron job

Tags: python, django, cron

I have a cron job scheduled that runs a custom management command in Django.  I would like to output all information on a success as well as a fail.  How would I structure this?

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['my_custom_command'])
]
```

I've tried setting up a relative path in settings like this

```
log_file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "log_files/cronjob.log")
```

and then tried the following 3 configurations but none of them worked

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command >> log_file_path', ['my_custom_command'])
]
```

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['my_custom_command', '>> log_file_path'])
]
```

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['my_custom_command >> log_file_path'])
]
```

I could also be structuring my relative path incorrectly but I've tried all of this with absolute paths as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to this.  The format that I used to set up the cron job requires an object before the log output path.

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'django.core.management.call_command', ['my_custom_command'], {}, '>> log_file_path')
]
```